# dropdown on custom shipping method magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add a dropdown at checkout page which has option of pick up time and pickupdate. currently I added shipping methods in dropdown I want to add pick up date and time instead of it.

```
    <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): ?>
<form id="co-shipping-method-form-drop" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>">
    <select id='drop_estimate_method' name="estimate_method">
        <option value='-1'>Please Select Shipping Method</option>
        <?php 
        foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates) { 
        $str = $this->getCarrierName($code);
        foreach ($_rates as $_rate){ 
            $str2 = $str . ' - ' . $_rate->getMethodTitle();

            $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax());
            $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true);
            $str2 .= ' ['. $_excl;
            if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl) { 
                $str2 .= ' '. $this->__('Incl. Tax'); echo $_incl;
            }
            $str2 .= '] ';
        ?>
        <option <?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' selected="selected"' ?> value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_rate->getCode()) ?>"><?php echo $str2;?></option>

        <?php } 
        } ?>
    </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        $('drop_estimate_method').observe('change',function(){
            if($('drop_estimate_method').getValue() == -1){
                alert('Please Select Shipping Method');
            }else{
                $('co-shipping-method-form-drop').submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```